# C# Oracle Database and Comboboxes Updating

Tags: c#, oracle, combobox

I am using Windows Forms in Visual Studio 2010 for C#.

I am programming a UI for a store.

I have a combobox attached to a Discount database table, displaying the DiscountDescription from that table.

I want to be able to retrieve the DiscountPercent based on the User's selection in the Combobox, so that I can calculate an accurate price.

Database table: Discount (Quick example of columns)

DiscountID:             1,        2,      3,        4,       5,      6 (Primary Key)

DiscountPercent:        0,       10,     10,       15,      20,     10

DiscountDescription: NONE, EMPLOYEE, IRVING, MILITARY, MANAGER, SENIOR

How do I get the DiscountPercent from this table, using a combobox selection?

Would it also work to run a query based on the Selected Value whenever I change the selection in the combobox?

An example of what I have so far.

```
         /private void discountDescriptionComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         //Geting the DiscountId
         int id = int.Parse(cboDiscount.SelectedValue.ToString());
         //dt = your data. You better know about your datasource. I assume there can be a datatable
         DataRow[] dr = nISSANDataset["Discount"].select('DiscountId = ' + id);
         txtDiscount.Text = dr[0]["DiscountPercent"].ToString();
    }

//This fills the combobox
private void PartsInvoice_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.discountTableAdapter.FillDiscount(this.nISSANDataset.Discount);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }          
    }
```

Comment: your question is too much messy. try to make the question simpler.

Comment: It would work on winforms, yes. Just catch the selectedindexchanged event

Comment: Problem is it doesn't work. I can't seem to grab that DiscountPercent when I pick something else in the combobox.

Comment: please help my question this is nearest topic
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45028694/load-data-oracle-table-to-c-sharp-combobox-using-oledb/45029017?noredirect=1#comment77032168_45029017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are loading your combobox with `DiscountID`. Ok. Fine.
2. on Selection Change event of the combobox, you can pick the `DiscountID`.
3. then you can retrive the `DiscountPrice` from the datasource.
4. Show the `DiscountPrice` on the textbox.

> ```
> >  private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs
> > e)
> >     {
> >     //Geting the DiscountId
> >     int id = int.Parse(cboDiscount.SelectedValue.ToString());
> >     //dt = your data. You better know about your datasource. I assume there can be a datatable
> >     DataRow[] dr = dt.select('DiscountId = ' + id);
> >     textbox1.Text = dr[0]["Discount"].ToString();
> >     }
> ```

**EDIT:** For Dataset

> ```
> >  private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs
> > e)
> >     {
> >     //Geting the DiscountId
> >     int id = int.Parse(cboDiscount.SelectedValue.ToString());
> >     //dt = your data. You better know about your datasource. I assume there can be a datatable
> >     DataRow[] dr = this.nISSANDataset.Tables["Discount"].select("DiscountId = " + id);
> >     textbox1.Text = dr[0]["DiscountPercent"].ToString();
> >     }
> ```

Comment: When I have Selected Value and Value Member as anything but DiscountID,the possible selections in the combobox change after I select one. I just need to get the DiscountPercent associate to the DiscountID/DiscountDescription into a variable, and I don't know the query or method or whatever to do that.

Comment: check it. Does it help?

Comment: It think it could, but the dt catches me. My database connection is through an Oracle connection via Add New Datasource. I have the discountBindingSource and discountTableAdapter, as well as the Dataset.

Comment: I tried that code. At first, it said Dataset didn't exist, so I changed it to DataSet, but it gave an error that it's being used as a variable despite being a type. So I replaced it with my variable nISSANDataset, but it doesn't see to want to accept the [] or anything I put into it.

Comment: "Cannot apply [] to a type myName.NISSANDataset"

Comment: add the code you are trying with your datasource variable, combobox name, textbox name etc. You should edit your question and add these thing. That will help to understand your situation.

Comment: Progress! It works until I get to the .Select(). It underlines 'DiscountID = ' as "Too Many Characters in Character Literal"

Comment: Put in double quotes and holy crap it's working! Thank you so much!

Comment: try " instead of '. i am updating the answer