# Load data Oracle Table to C# combobox using Oledb

Tags: c#, sql, oracle11g, combobox, oledbconnection

hello i have create a table **buy_unit** in oracle database

> CREATE TABLE  buy_unit(
>   unit_id  NUMBER(10) not null PRIMARY KEY,
>   unit_name VARCHAR2(10) not null
>   );

and insert Values

> INSERT INTO BUY_UNIT
>   values(001,'Liter');
>   desc SELL_BUY_UNIT;

then create  a combo box  **combobox1** in C# now can  load  buy_unit table data in combobox ? i have use the connection:

> OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=XE;User ID=user1;password=pssword");

Comment: Why do you want to use Oledb (good for MS Access only) why not OracleClient .Share your C# code here. How you are fetching data, how you are storing in memory and binding etc.

Comment: @Prathyush ,Dear i am beginner , start learning now. i  need just load data in combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can see below code which is refering SQLConnection. You can change as per your DB may be OracleConnection or so. While using SQL, we have pass connection string with UID and PWD.

For Oracle
have connection string as

```
string con = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST = 000.00.0.00)(PORT = 0000)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = database)));User ID=User/Schema;Password=password;Unicode=True";

public void BindComboBox()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=ServerName; database = DBName ;  User Id=sa; Password=PeaTeaCee5#");
    con.Open();
    string strCmd = "select desire column from table";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCmd, con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strCmd, con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    cbSupportID.DisplayMember = "name to display";
    cbSupportID.ValueMember = "id";       
    cbSupportID.DataSource = ds;

    cbSupportID.Enabled = true;

}
```

and try to use using block when you open DB connection as below

```
using (OracleConnection objConn = new OracleConnection(con))
 {
   \\ you code
   \\ do your stuff
 }
```

Code for Oracle. Excuse for syntax.

```
public  void  Fillcombo()
        {
            string oradb = " Data Source=xe;User Id=dbname;Password=pws; ";
            string query = "select id , name from table";
            OracleConnection condatabase = new OracleConnection(oradb);
            OracleCommand cmddatabase = new OracleCommand(query, condatabase);

            try
            {
                condatabase.Open();
                OracleDataReader myReader = cmddatabase.ExecuteReader(); ;
                myReader = cmddatabase.ExecuteReader();
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    string sname = myReader.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(sname.ToString());
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank for your code and i will  try it, i need   the code for oracle please if possible .

Comment: sorry can not execute success ,  need oracle code please

Comment: i am tired any new code for  C# combobox   for oracle database? thanks